# IE has empty document.referrer after a location.replace

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a site that does a complex search and has a "loading" page.  On the loading page we use:

`<body onload="window.location.replace('results_page.php');" >`

Or:

`<body onload="window.location = 'results_page.php';" >`

The only difference between the two option above are that location.replace() ignores the page in the browser's history.

On the results_page I need to read the referrer for tracking purposes:

`<script> alert(document.referrer); </script>`

This works fine on all browsers except IE, which returns and empty value for `document.referrer`.

Anyone know a better way to do a javascript redirect that will give IE a value for the referrer?

p.s. This example has been made much more simple than it would be in production.

Comment: What happens in IE when you set the url to window.location like this: `window.location= 'results_page.php'`?

Answer (score 24):

Looks like this is just the cost of doing business with IE users.  Can't be fixed without a hack.  Working on one now.  Thanks for listening.

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html

I used the workaround to make this function. Works like a charm.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >            
function redirect(url) {
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        var referLink = document.createElement('a');
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    } else {
        location.href = url;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow matt thank you so much, been looking everywhere for a fix for this! IE9 handles a normal location.href fine, so with jQuery I made it simply `if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) <= 8 )` You rule!

Answer (score 3):

**INFO: Internet Explorer Does Not Send Referer Header in Unsecured Situations**

When linking from one document to another in Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, the Referer header will not be sent when the link is from an HTTPS page to a non-HTTPS page. The Referer header also will not be sent when the link is from a non-HTTP(S) protocol, such as file://, to another page.

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Matt answer this code snippet also detects IE11 and opens url in new tab. On Microsoft Edge browser no additional changes are required to pass document.referrer with window.location.replace.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openUrlNewTab(url) {
    //use userAgent to detect <IE11 and window obj to detect IE11
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) || 
       (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode)) {
      var el = document.createElement('a');
      el.href = url;
      el.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(el);
      el.click();
    } else {
      window.open(url);
    }
  }
</script>
```