# Programmatically set the referrer on javascript redirect

Tags: javascript

Is there a *cross-browser* way to call Javascript `setLocation()` but still to keep the referrer to the one that lead to the current webpage (just like in HTTP server-side redirect) and if yes then how?

Clarifying example:

`Site A` sent a user to `Site B`.

When arriving on `Site B`, `Site A` is the referrer.
When redirecting from `Site B` to `Site C` (by adjusting the location in JS), `Site B` will be referrer.
I'd like to keep the original referrer (i.e. `Site A`) when redirecting from `B` to `C`.

Comment: It must be already set, just like if you would click on a link.
[javascript - Is the REFERER set if you redirect to a new web page using location.href =? - Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657558/is-the-referer-set-if-you-redirect-to-a-new-web-page-using-location-href

Comment: added an example to clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

It is seems like you need a referrer history persistence, you can use query-string to achieve it easily:

```
www.c.com/?originalReferrer=A
```

Comment: Thanks, though history persistence is a different case.