# Document.referrer issue on IE when the requests doesn't come from a link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, document

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE has empty document.referrer after a location.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890532/ie-has-empty-document-referrer-after-a-location-replace)

Hi there,

I have got an issue on using the document.referrer property in IE. When I get to a page not through a link but changing the window.location through JavaScript, the document.referrer of the destination page is empty in IE7/8. Any idea on how to get around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the old page url in a cookie.

Or add the referer to the url in the fragment identifier.

```
location.href = 'page.html' + '#' + location.href
```

Or create a link on the fly with javascript, and call it's .click(). So something like

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href='page.html';
document.body.appendChild(a);//not sure if this is needed
a.click();
```