# document.referrer does not work in ie

Tags: javascript

I've been searching the internet for a while to find an answer, but have had no luck.

`document.referrer` in ie does not work.

I need to find the previous url without storing in local storage, cookies or setting sessions. Is there any way to do this?

I am not creating a back button or a link so `window.history` does not work in this situation. I need to perform an action to display an element based on where they previously were.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Helium_1s2, unfortunately not. That is creating a link for a back button.

Comment: What does `document.referrer` returns in IE?

Comment: @Ibu, it returns blank because ie doesn't return that header. From what I have been reading it is a known issue, but have found no solutions. i was hoping maybe someone had a trick :)

Comment: You could encode it into the url itself, as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847615/document-referrer-issue-on-ie-when-the-requests-doesnt-come-from-a-link

Comment: Simply store it somewhere else. That's your only option. You can use any of the things you said you don't want to use, or any number of other possible similar alternatives. But they're all fundamentally the same: Store it somewhere else.

Comment: @helium I can’t change the url at all. There are too many variables in the url and it will cause confusion/won’t be accurate.

Comment: @kevin, it’s not that I don’t “want” to use them it’s that I cannot use them. The app has  built in cache busting between pages  due to business requirements

Comment: That is unfortunate, but it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @chiliNUT no, I cannot set a cookie :(

Comment: If the information is not there, there's no way to create it. Note that all the potential workarounds only work if the previous page is under your control.