# Save current window URL and move back to that URL after couple of navigation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a site and in my site when user click on a specific div then a new child window open . Suppose the user is standing at `xyz.com/category` , now if you user clicks on that div then parent windows goes to another url suppose `google.com` and a  popup window will get open and there are some more navigation in popup windows . But every page that will open in popup has a button called `Go Back To Site`  . I want that when user clicks on several links in popup and then click on `Go Back To Site` button then popup window get closed and parent window move back to `xyz.com/category`.

Comment: is `xyz.com/category` always the same?

Comment: No @Josh this is dynamic , it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP Superglobal array

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is null in IE

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **javascript** for this, there are simple functions such as:

```
window.history.back();

window.history.forward();
```

You can refer all of them in following link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

**For Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

**For C# :**

```
WebBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://maps.google.com");
```

**- document.referrer does not work for IE**

For this issue refer following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >            
function redirect(url) {
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        var referLink = document.createElement('a');
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    } else {
        location.href = url;
    }
}
</script>
```

This code can also be refered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890532/ie-has-empty-document-referrer-after-a-location-replace)

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is to pass the current URL as a parameter into your popup. So you would change your anchor link tags to this:

```
<a href="popup.aspx?prevPage=oldPage.aspx">Click</a>
```

So when your popup pops up, you just grab the value of prevPage and then when they click "Back to previous page", you just redirect to the value of prevPage.